# Laravel form update file is null

Tags: php, laravel-5

i was just trying to upload my file to laravel

This is my upload view

```
<form action="/DoUpload" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="Image" value="Image">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

this is my upload controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $IMAGE = $request->file('Image');
    dd($IMAGE);
    }
```

when i try to dd the image, the page said that it is null..

Comment: add `file="true"` in your form. It will solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `multipart/form-data` `enctype` for your form, Like:

```
<form action="/DoUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="file" name="Image" value="Image">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Upload!">
</form>
```

this will be able to send files through `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel then try to follow its LaravelCollective/html package.

In LaravelCollective this can be solve by just a simple line

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'your_url', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true))}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

which will create

```
<form action="your_url" method="post" files="true">
```

in laravel `files=true` do same the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` do.